# How can I associate two values in Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

This seems like something that should be easy to do but I can't find any workable solutions. The basic idea is to have an array with codes associated to urls, and depending which url is parsed as a referrer, a code is inserted in localStorage.

```
var site = {
“example1.com” : "x10",
“example2.com” : "x11",
“example3.com” : "x12"
}

if (document.referrer.indexOf(sitevalue) != -1) {    

   if (localStorage) { 
   localStorage.setItem("code",sitekey);
}
}
```

So if the referrer is example1.com, then the code set in localStorage will "x10" and so on. I have read about possibly using the Underscore.js _Invert method, but I think there's gotta be a more obvious solution I am missing.

Comment: it's just an object. `.setItem("code", site['example1.com'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly inefficient, as it keeps processing after it finds the match, but it's very simple code:

```
Object.keys(site).forEach(function(key) {
    if (document.referrer.indexOf(key) > -1) {
        if (localStorage) { 
            localStorage.setItem("code", site[key]);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Update**: Just noticed the Underscore tag.  With Underscore, I might change the looping slightly, to do this instead:

```
_.forEach(_.pairs(site), function(pair) {
    if (document.referrer.indexOf(pair[0]) > -1) {
        if (localStorage) { 
            localStorage.setItem("code", pair[1]);
        }
    }
});
```

The only significant advantage is that this might work in older environments that don't support `Object.keys`, or `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `"x10"` you can get it via `site["example1.com"]`, etc.

I'm sure about your specific requirement, but this would solve what I understood:

```
var site = {
    "example1.com" : "x10",
    "example2.com" : "x11",
    "example3.com" : "x12"
}

if (document.referrer.indexOf(sitevalue) != -1) {    
    if (localStorage) {
        var url = document.referrer.replace('www.','')
        var host = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
        localStorage.setItem("code", site[host]);
    }
}
```

Please note that I added some more code, to remove a possible leading `www.` as well as retireving the hostname from the provided URL via a regular expression.

Comment: Bear in mind that the object keys aren't necessarily the *whole* of the string provided by `document.referrer` (which is why I deleted my answer, I didn't have the time to sanitise the provided URL to retrieve the hostName).

Comment: @DavidThomas Good point. I'll take the time and update my answer.

Comment: I understand I can get the value from they key, wouldn't using 'site[document.referrer]' only work with an exact url? I'm using the first if statement to check wether my key is present in the url, then if it is, assigning the associated code. It needs to be dynamic so simply using 'site["example1.com"]' would only work for that url right?

Comment: @Epleroma Right. But note that I updated my answer, trimming `document.referrer` down to the host name (without `www`).

Comment: Had not seen the edited answer. Thank you! I noticed you kept the first if statement, which did the same check that is done in the localStorage part of your solution now. Would it make sense to change that one to check wether the key exists? If the user comes from a site not defined in the array I want to avoid an "undefined" localStorage object.

Comment: @Epleroma You coud of course swith the two if statements so that you fill `localStorage` with a fallback value or something. I don't know what exactly you need, but I'm sure, you'll figure it out. Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes! Testing solutions now, and I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions to get the host, you can make the browser do it for you: `function getHost(URL){ var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = URL; return a.hostname; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leverage Underscore.js, the following standalone working example illustrates how to loop through the keys in  your `site` object, and if one matches a referer string, then stash its corresponding code in localStorage.

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script>

    // this variable is just for testing
    var myReferer = "http://example2.com";

    var site = {
        "example1.com": "x10",
        "example2.com": "x11",
        "example3.com": "x12"
    };

    if (localStorage) {
        _.each(site, function (value, key) {
            // you'd replace "myReferer" with "document.referrer" here
            if (myReferer.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                localStorage.setItem("code", value);
            }
        });
    }

    // this is also just for testing
    alert(localStorage["code"]);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, works great, but I ended up using the simpler JS only solution for now. However having the underscore.js way is great for a different site where I plan to use this in the future.

Comment: D'oh!  In my Underscore solution, I forgot that _.each can be used on objects.  I guess I've just had my brain stuck in my own [Ramda](https://github.com/CrossEye/ramda) library!  :-)

Comment: @Scott Your use of built-in JavaScript methods like `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()` is way cooler anyways. As long as we don't have to support older versions of _that-browser-I-shall-not-mention-here_...

Comment: @TroyGizzi: Oh, please, mention it.  Halloween's coming up.  We all could use a good scare.